# hide div after postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using file upload inside update panel so i added PostBackTrigger to btnsubmit to make it work.

```
<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnsubmit" />
```

The issue is `divtrue` or `divfalse` are supposed to be hided after page refresh.

The below code used to hide div but it wont hided after i added PostBackTrigger.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.Form.Attributes.Add("enctype", "multipart/form-data");

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        gridItem.DataSource = i.GetItems();
        gridItem.DataBind();
    }

    divfalse.Visible = false;
    divtrue.Visible = false;
}
```

**btnsubmit Code**

```
string imgPath;
protected void btnsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
         if (imgup.HasFile)
         {
            string imgName = imgup.FileName.ToString();
            imgup.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Images/") + imgName);
            imgPath = "Images/" + imgName;
         }
        string msg=i.AddItem(txtitemcode.Text,imgPath,DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
        if (msg == "true")
        {
            gridItem.DataSource = i.GetItems();
            gridItem.DataBind();
            MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 0;
            divtrue.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 0;
            divfalse.Visible = true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write("Error: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

**Update-panel**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:MultiView ID="MultiView1" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0">
            <asp:View ID="View1" runat="server">
                <div class="alert alert-success" runat="server" id="divtrue">
                    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
                    <strong>Success!</strong>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbltrue" runat="server" Text="Item added successfully."></asp:Label>
                </div>
                <div class="alert alert-danger" runat="server" id="divfalse">
                    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
                    <strong>Error!</strong>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblfalse" runat="server" Text="Item not aadded please try again."></asp:Label>
                </div>
            </asp:View>
<asp:View ID="View2" runat="server">
        <%--Adding form %>

                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnsubmit" runat="server" OnClick="btnsubmit_Click" class="btn btn-primary" Text="Submit" Width="100px" ValidationGroup="g1" />
                        </div>
            </asp:View>
        </asp:MultiView>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnsubmit" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: your div code should be inside update panel

Comment: post your update panel code.

Comment: Nazir Ullah its inside the update panel

Comment: Set UpdateMode to `always`

Comment: Akash Amin nothing changes

Comment: Please post your update panel code.

Comment: ok i added update panel code

Answer (score -1):

Try using the following instead:

```
divfalse.Attributes.Add("style", "display:none;");
```